# recursive function happening before object can update

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I"m building a tic tac toe game that has one player playing the computer and is only allowed to at best tie. My play defense function should find any time the player has two adjacent row col and the third is empty, it should choose that space automatically. Then update the gameboard object to show what the computer controls and what the player controls. Then increments the number of moves, checks for a winner, and if no winner changes players turns. Stepping through the code though,the computer plays first just fine but as soon as the player chooses their square before the gameboard can update the computer has already chosen the next choice. So it doesn't adapt to the player and loses. I'm not aware that I've used any asynchronous functions so I'm not sure why it is happening before the players gameboard choice has been updated. Here is relevant code but I think it might be easier to run through codepen link underneath.

```
function computeMove(game, lastMove, move){
 if((game.a1==""&&game.a2=="C"&&game.a3=="C")||
 (game.a1==""&&game.b1=="C"&&game.c1=="C")||
 (game.a1==""&&game.b2=="C"&&game.c3=="C"))
 {
    $('#col-a1').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-a1';
    changeValue(computer, item);
 }
 else if((game.a2=""&&game.a1=="C"&&game.a3=="C")||
     (game.a2==""&&game.b2=="C"&&game.c2=="C"))
  {
    $('#col-a2').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-a2';
    changeValue(computer, item);
  }
else if((game.a1=="C" && game.a2=="C" && game.a3=="")||
   (game.a3=="" && game.b2=="C" && game.c1=="C")||
   (game.a3=="" && game.b3=="C" && game.c3=="C"))
  {
    $('#col-a3').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-a3';
    changeValue(computer, item);
  }
else if((game.b1=="" && game.b2=="C" && game.b3=="C")||
     (game.a1=="C" && game.b1=="" && game.c1=="C"))
  {
    $('#col-b1').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-b1';
    changeValue(computer, item);
  }
else if((game.b2==""&&game.b1=="C"&&game.b3=="C")||
     (game.b2==""&&game.a2=="C"&&game.c2=="C")||
     (game.b2==""&&game.a1=="C"&&game.c3=="C")||
     (game.b2==""&&game.a3=="C"&&game.c1=="C"))
  {
    $('#col-b2').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-b2';
    changeValue(computer, item);
  }
else if((game.b3==""&&game.b1=="C"&&game.b2=="C")||
     (game.b3==""&&game.a3=="C"&&game.c3=="C"))
  {
    $('#col-b3').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-b3';
    changeValue(computer, item);
  }
else if((game.c1==""&&game.c2=="C"&&game.c3=="C")||
     (game.c1==""&&game.a1=="C"&&game.b1=="C")||
     (game.c1==""&&game.b2=="C"&&game.a3=="C"))
  {
    $('#col-c1').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-c1';
    changeValue(computer, item);
  }
else if((game.c2==""&&game.c1=="C"&&game.c3=="C")||
     (game.c2==""&&game.b2=="C"&&game.a2=="C"))
  {
    $('#col-c2').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-c2';
    changeValue(computer, item);
  }
else if((game.c3==""&&game.c1=="C"&&game.c2=="C")||
     (game.c3==""&&game.b3=="C"&&game.a3=="C")||
     (game.c3==""&&game.b2=="C"&&game.a1=="C"))
  {
    $('#col-c3').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-c3';
    changeValue(computer, item);
  }
else
  {
    playDefense(game, lastMove, move)
  }
}

function playDefense(game, lastMove, move)
  {
    if((game.a1==""&&game.a2=="P"&&game.a3=="P")||
     (game.a1==""&&game.b1=="P"&&game.c1=="P")||
     (game.a1==""&&game.b2=="P"&&game.c3=="P"))
    {
      $('#col-a1').html(computer.choose());
      var item = 'col-a1';
      changeValue(computer, item);
    }
   else if((game.a2=""&&game.a1=="P"&&game.a3=="P")||
     (game.a2==""&&game.b2=="P"&&game.c2=="P"))
    {
      $('#col-a2').html(computer.choose());
      var item = 'col-a2';
      changeValue(computer, item);
    }
  else if((game.a1=="P" && game.a2=="P" && game.a3=="")||
     (game.a3=="" && game.b2=="P" && game.c1=="P")||
     (game.a3=="" && game.b3=="P" && game.c3=="P"))
  {
    $('#col-a3').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-a3';
    changeValue(computer, item);
  }
 else if((game.b1=="" && game.b2=="P" && game.b3=="P")||
     (game.a1=="P" && game.b1=="" && game.c1=="P"))
  {
    $('#col-b1').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-b1';
    changeValue(computer, item);
  }
 else if((game.b2==""&&game.b1=="P"&&game.b3=="P")||
     (game.b2==""&&game.a2=="P"&&game.c2=="P")||
     (game.b2==""&&game.a1=="P"&&game.c3=="P")||
     (game.b2==""&&game.a3=="P"&&game.c1=="P"))
 {
    $('#col-b2').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-b2';
    changeValue(computer, item);
 }
else if((game.b3==""&&game.b1=="P"&&game.b2=="P")||
     (game.b3==""&&game.a3=="P"&&game.c3=="P"))
 {
    $('#col-b3').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-b3';
    changeValue(computer, item);
 }
else if((game.c1==""&&game.c2=="P"&&game.c3=="P")||
     (game.c1==""&&game.a1=="P"&&game.b1=="P")||
     (game.c1==""&&game.b2=="P"&&game.a3=="P"))
 {
    $('#col-c1').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-c1';
    changeValue(computer, item);
 }
else if((game.c2==""&&game.c1=="P"&&game.c3=="P")||
     (game.c2==""&&game.b2=="P"&&game.a2=="P"))
 {
    $('#col-c2').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-c2';
    changeValue(computer, item);
 }
else if((game.c3==""&&game.c1=="P"&&game.c2=="P")||
     (game.c3==""&&game.b3=="P"&&game.a3=="P")||
     (game.c3==""&&game.b2=="P"&&game.a1=="P"))
 {
    $('#col-c3').html(computer.choose());
    var item = 'col-c3';
    changeValue(computer, item);
 }
else
 {
  findPlayerMove(game, lastMove, move)
 }
}

function findPlayerMove(game, lastMove, move)
 {
  if(move==2)
    {
      if(lastMove=="col-a1")
        {
          $('#col-c3').html(computer.choose());
         var item = 'col-c3';
         changeValue(computer, item);
        }
      else if(lastMove=="col-a3")
        {
          $('#col-c1').html(computer.choose());
           var item = 'col-c1';
           changeValue(computer, item);
        }
      else if(lastMove=="col-c1")
        {
          $('#col-a3').html(computer.choose());
          var item = 'col-a3';
          changeValue(computer, item);
        }
      else if(lastMove=="col-c3")
        {
         $('#col-a1').html(computer.choose());
         var item = 'col-a1';
         changeValue(computer, item);
       }
      else if(lastMove=="col-a2")
        {
         $('#col-c3').html(computer.choose());
         var item = 'col-c3';
         changeValue(computer, item);
        }
      else if(lastMove=="col-b1")
        {
          $('#col-c3').html(computer.choose());
           var item = 'col-c3';
           changeValue(computer, item);
        }
      else if(lastMove=="col-b3")
        {
          $('#col-c1').html(computer.choose());
          var item = 'col-c1';
          changeValue(computer, item);
        }
      else if(lastMove=="col-c2")
        {
          $('#col-a3').html(computer.choose());
          var item = 'col-a3';
          changeValue(computer, item);
        }
    }
  else if(move==4)
  {
    if(lastMove=="col-a2")
      {
        if(game.c3=="")
          {
            $('#col-c3').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-c3';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
        else if(game.c1=="")
          {
            $('#col-c1').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-c1';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
      }
    else if(lastMove=="col-b1")
      {
        if(game.a3=="P"&&game.a1=="")
          {
            $('#col-a1').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-a1';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
        else if(game.c3=="P"&&game.c1=="")
          {
            $('#col-c1').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-c1';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
      }
    else if(lastMove=="col-b3")
      {
        if(game.a1=="P"&&game.c1=="")
          {
            $('#col-c1').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-c1';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
        else if(game.c1=="P"&&game.c3=="")
          {
            $('#col-c3').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-c3';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
      }
    else if(lastMove=="col-c2")
      {
        if(game.a1=="P"&&game.c1=="")
          {
            $('#col-c1').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-c1';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
        else if(game.c1=="P"&&game.c3=="")
          {
            $('#col-c3').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-c3';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
        else if(game.a3=="P"&&game.c3=="")
          {
            $('#col-c3').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-c3';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
      }
  }
if(move==6)
  {
    if(lastMove=="col-a2")
      {
        if(game.b1=="")
          {
            $('#col-b1').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-b1';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
      }
    else if(lastMove=="col-b1")
      {
        if(game.a2=="")
          {
            $('#col-a2').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-a2';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
      }
    else if(lastMove=="col-b3")
      {
         if(game.a2=="")
          {
            $('#col-a2').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-a2';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
      }
    else if(lastMove=="col-c2")
      {
        if(game.b1=="")
          {
            $('#col-b1').html(computer.choose());
            var item = 'col-b1';
            changeValue(computer, item);
          }
      }
  }
if(move==8)
  {
    if(game.a1=="")
      {
        $('#col-a1').html(computer.choose());
        var item = 'col-a1';
        changeValue(computer, item);
      }
    if(game.a2=="")
      {
        $('#col-a2').html(computer.choose());
        var item = 'col-a2';
        changeValue(computer, item);
      }
    if(game.a3=="")
      {
        $('#col-a3').html(computer.choose());
        var item = 'col-a3';
        changeValue(computer, item);
      }
    if(game.b1=="")
      {
        $('#col-b1').html(computer.choose());
        var item = 'col-b1';
        changeValue(computer, item);
      }
    if(game.b3=="")
      {
        $('#col-b3').html(computer.choose());
        var item = 'col-b3';
        changeValue(computer, item);
      }
    if(game.c1=="")
      {
        $('#col-c1').html(computer.choose());
        var item = 'col-c1';
        changeValue(computer, item);
      }
    if(game.c2=="")
      {
        $('#col-c2').html(computer.choose());
        var item = 'col-c2';
        changeValue(computer, item);
      }
    if(game.c3=="")
      {
        $('#col-c3').html(computer.choose());
        var item = 'col-c3';
        changeValue(computer, item);
      }
  }
}

function changeValue(pl, col)
    {
        console.log("This is the current player: ")
  console.log(pl);
        console.log("This is the current col: " + col);
  if(pl.name == "Player One")
    {
      if (col=="col-a1") {
          cGameBoard.a1='P';
      } else if (col=="col-a2") {
          cGameBoard.a2='P';
      } else if (col=="col-a3") {
          cGameBoard.a3='P';
      } else if (col=="col-b1") {
          cGameBoard.b1='P';
      } else if (col=="col-b2") {
          cGameBoard.b2='P';
      } else if (col=="col-b3") {
          cGameBoard.b3='P';
      } else if (col=="col-c1") {
          cGameBoard.c1='P';
      } else if (col=="col-c2") {
          cGameBoard.c2='P';
      } else if (col=="col-c3") {
          cGameBoard.c3='P';
      } else {
          alert("ChangeValue not working");
      }
    }
  else
    {
      if (col=="col-a1") {
                cGameBoard.a1='C';
      } else if (col=="col-a2") {
          cGameBoard.a2='C';
      } else if (col=="col-a3") {
          cGameBoard.a3='C';
      } else if (col=="col-b1") {
          cGameBoard.b1='C';
      } else if (col=="col-b2") {
          cGameBoard.b2='C';
      } else if (col=="col-b3") {
          cGameBoard.b3='C';
      } else if (col=="col-c1") {
          cGameBoard.c1='C';
      } else if (col=="col-c2") {
          cGameBoard.c2='C';
      } else if (col=="col-c3") {
          cGameBoard.c3='C';
      } else {
          alert("ChangeValue not working");
      }
    }
            console.log("gameboard before winnercheck");
  console.log(cGameBoard);
    }

  var move = 0;
  function playGame(){
    if($('#well-info').text()=='')
     {
       if(computer.turn)
        {
          if(move == 0)
            {
              $('#col-b2').html(computer.choose());
              var item = 'col-b2';
              changeValue(computer, item);
              move++;
              winnerCheck(cGameBoard);
              player1.turn = true;
              computer.turn = false;
              playGame();
            }
          else
           {
             computeMove(cGameBoard, lastMove, move);
             move++;
             winnerCheck(cGameBoard);
             player1.turn = true;
             computer.turn = false;
             playGame();
           }
       }
     else if(player1.turn)
      {
        console.log("It is player 1 turn")
        $('.status').click(function(event){
        console.log("Got the click event");
        var $item = $(this).attr('id');
          console.log("This is $item");
          console.log($item);
        if($.trim($('#'+$item).html())=='')
          {
            console.log("The box was empty");
            $('#' + $item).html(player1.choose());
            lastMove = $item;
            changeValue(player1, $item);
            move++;
            winnerCheck(cGameBoard);
            player1.turn = false;
            computer.turn = true;
            playGame();
          }
        else
          {
            $('#' + $item).toggleClass("highlighted");
            setTimeout(function() {
               $('#' + $item).removeClass("highlighted")
             }, 1000);
          }
         });
        }
     }
 }
```

http://codepen.io/RawleJuglal/pen/mVOMyd

Comment: After more troubleshooting I found why it seemed like it was updating. That was a syntax error. I am having a new issue with the click event in the playGame function. It seems like every click after the first time is firing mulitple events. I read about using on/off and unbind but I'm having trouble getting the right syntax without breaking the whole thing. It will be important that every time a col with the class status gets clicked it gives me the id of that col but after it has been clicked once I don't want it to be allowed to be clicked again. Can anyone give me insight on how to do this?

Comment: New codepen link to show where I'm at

http://codepen.io/RawleJuglal/pen/obYJBR/